In Visual Basic (Windows Forms) how can I add a label to a MenuStrip?
I created a Windows Form in Visual Basic which contains a MenuStrip. I need to add a label in that MenuStrip which should display the current user's login details and domain info but for some reason I can't drag and drop a label in that MenuStrip. Any help would be highly appreciated!
I went through VB tutorials on how to add labels in Windows forms. I also tried adding different objects such as 'buttons' but still did not work
I'm hoping to get an answer on how to add a label to a Windows form that contains a label which will display the current user details

I think you can right-click on your solution explorer, go to Add and find in the list it presents something about adding a User Control. It is like a form and you should be able to place a MenuStrip and a Label on this custom control. It's been a long time for me. But it's not difficult. Have you looked into that process?

@periblepsis Thank you for taking the time to replay so quickly! I looked into that but still could not find the appropriate option. I'll keep trying, and once I come across a solution, I'll post it here.

I could refresh my memory. But it would take time and I suspect there must be a few pages on the topic somewhere. I'm glad to hear you will post up an answer when you find one. You are motivated and must put in the work. And it may help others wanting something similar. In the meantime, I can at least dig into old code to see what I did "back in the day." Maybe something more concrete and useful.

Okay. Yeah. I found a simple project where I developed a simple custom control with four checkboxes and a button on it. That custom control is then just dragged and dropped onto a regular form. Once you make the custom control and compile things (and maybe reload the project?) then the new control appears in the toolbox so that it is very easy to apply to forms. (It won't be in the Common Controls area, though.) When I get a moment I might find time to write something.

"for some reason I can't drag and drop a label in that MenuStrip". The reason is that a MenuStrip, which inherits ToolStrip doesn't host just any control. It will only host a type that inherits ToolStripItem. I think that you should be able to add a ToolStripControlHost and host an arbitrary control in that. That's where you should direct your research. That said, the MenuStrip may have additional limitations over the ToolStrip. The best option may be to simply use a regular menu item and then configure it to behave the way you want.

@Sammie I remember the details of how to achieve it now. But it's a pain. You will need to do your own paint code -- owner draw, in short. The MenuStrip won't work nicely with a Label control sitting on top of it. It will work erratically or not at all. So you will need to derive a control (normal derivation) and implement owner-draw. You can then add your own text into the derived control, add a property, and paint it any way you want. I remember enough, now, that I could just sit down and do it. Not sure I want to write that for you, though. Look up owner-draw and derived control.

@periblepsis, no need for all that. The ToolStripControlHost can host any WinForms control.

@jmcilhinney, I researched your method and found the set of instructions below

Add a ToolStripMenuItem to your form where you want the label.
In the Properties window, change the Text property to "Find" and the Name property to an appropriate value, e.g. "findToolStripLabel".
Click the 'Show All Files' button at the top of the Solution Explorer.
Expand the node for the form in the Solution Explorer.
Double-click the Designer.vb file for the form to open the designer code file.
Change references to the ToolStripMenuItem type for the item added above to ToolStripLabel


@jmcilhinney your method worked :)
Thank you all so very much for taking the time to help!!

It's not uncommon to add a StatusStrip control to the bottom of the Form, to display user and connection information. With a StatusStrip, you can add sections and ToolStripStatusLabel controls.

I just added this class to a project:
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

<ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip)>
Public Class ToolStripLabel
    Inherits ToolStripControlHost

    Public ReadOnly Property Label As Label
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Control, Label)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New Label)
    End Sub

End Class

After building, when I clicked the drop-down to add a new item to a MenuStrip, there was a Label option in the list, along with the usual MenuItem, ComboBox and TextBox. After adding one and opening the Properties window, I was able to expand the Label control and configure it like any other Label.

A couple of notes: - the ToolStripLabel name is already assigned to a standard Component; if you generate a new custom Component with that name, you end up causing trouble (disrupts existing inheritance) - why not just derive from the standard ToolStripLabel (used by the ToolStrip), then decorate it as you're doing here, so it can also be used in a MenuStrip? -- If you introduce a ToolStripControlHost, you also need to handle a LayoutEngine / Renderer that generate standard alignment, and also cope with DPI changes

@Jimi, fair call, although I'm not sure what you mean disrupting inheritance. I would think that there'd be no issue other than having to qualify the Microsoft type name. I knew there was a ToolStripStatisLabel but clearly didn't look hard enough for a ToolStripLabel. Your suggestion to inherit the existing class and add the attribute sounds good but I wonder whether it would behave as intended. There must be some reason they didn't make it supported on a MenuStrip in the first place.

Disrupting inheritance: if any class is declared as derived from a Component and the Component's namespace is not fully qualified (usually is not), a class in the current assembly that declares the same name has precedence. So you avoid that, in general -- The ToolStripLabel is just a ToolStripItem as all the others (ToolStripControlHost included). It uses the default Layout and Renderer, so RTL settings are preserved, and it's of course disposed as all other Components in the hierarchy

As to why it's not part of the MenuStrip's Components by default, just a guess: 90% of its code is there to handle the Link functionality. Maybe it's not considered an important feature in a container that is supposed present choices as Menus. But nothing is there to prevent anyone from making a different call (WinForms is kind of made with this in mind. When you're not supposed to change the behavior of a standard Class, one or more elements are sealed / internal. That's the clue you'll have to reinvent your own wheel)

I found this set of instructions that helped resolve this issue

Add a ToolStripMenuItem to your form where you want the label.
In the Properties window, change the Text property to "Find" and the Name property to an appropriate value, e.g. "findToolStripLabel".
Click the 'Show All Files' button at the top of the Solution Explorer.
Expand the node for the form in the Solution Explorer.
Double-click the Designer.vb file for the form to open the designer code file.
Change references to the ToolStripMenuItem type for the item added above to ToolStripLabel

